# Custom RoleProvider Not Called

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, roleprovider

My application has custom Role and MembershipProviders. I've registered them in web.config, but when I try to do `if(User.IsInRole("Blah"))`, neither of my breakpoints in the RoleProvider's `Initialize` or `IsUserInRole` are hit. The membership provider works fine, so I guess there must be something I've missed from web.config. This is what I have:

```
  <system.web>
    ...
    <membership defaultProvider="MyAppMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="MyAppMembershipProvider" 
             type="MyAppMembership.MyAppMembershipProvider" 
             connectionStringName="MyApp" 
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" writeExceptionsToEventLog="false" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <roleManager defaultProvider="MyAppRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MyAppRoleProvider"
             type="MyAppMembership.MyAppRoleProvider"
             connectionStringName="MyApp"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" writeExceptionsToEventLog="false" />
      </providers>      
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
```

Is there something else which I need?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The attribute `enabled` of the the `<roleManager>`-Element defaults to `false`! Try:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyAppRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MyAppRoleProvider"
             type="MyAppMembership.MyAppRoleProvider"
             connectionStringName="MyApp"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" writeExceptionsToEventLog="false" />
      </providers>      
    </roleManager>
```

Comment: It had to be something simple. Thanks.

Comment: @Echilon: Yeah, sometimes it's easier to get the "hard" stuff right. :-)